# The call stack result of profile-report doesn't match the real function codes

Tags: debugging, profiler, macroexpansion

I'm trying to figure out why my emacs was slow tonight and found:

```
- command-execute                                               82796  87%
 - call-interactively                                           82792  87%
  - funcall-interactively                                       82792  87%
   - evil-ex-search-forward                                     42805  45%
    - apply                                                     42805  45%
     - #<compiled 0x1891b35>                                    42805  45%
      - apply                                                   42805  45%
       - #<compiled 0x17e0a1d>                                  42802  45%
        - evil-ex-start-search                                  42802  45%
         - read-string                                          42783  45%
          - redisplay_internal (C function)                     42587  45%
           - eval                                               42567  45%
            - awesome-tab-line                                  42557  45%
             - cond                                             42557  45%
              - or                                              42550  45%
               - awesome-tab-line-format                        42550  45%
                - let*                                          42544  45%
                 - while                                        42540  45%
                  - setq                                        42540  45%
                   - cons                                       42540  45%
                    - awesome-tab-line-tab                      42540  45%
                     - propertize                               42540  45%
                      - awesome-tab-buffer-tab-label              42540  45%
                       - let*                                   42540  45%
                        - concat                                42540  45%
                         - if                                   42522  45%
                          - awesome-tab-icon-for-tab              42522  45%
                           - if                                 42522  45%
                            - and                               42380  45%
                             - condition-case                   42374  45%
                                progn                           42374  45%
                            + progn                               142   0%
```

As the result shows, `awesome-tab-icon-for-tab` is the root cause. Here is the definition of `awesome-tab-icon-for-tab`:

```
(defun awesome-tab-icon-for-tab (tab face)
  "When tab buffer's file is exists, use `all-the-icons-icon-for-file' to fetch file icon.
Otherwise use `all-the-icons-icon-for-buffer' to fetch icon for buffer."
  (when (and awesome-tab-display-icon
             (ignore-errors (require 'all-the-icons)))
    (let* ((tab-buffer (car tab))
           (tab-file (buffer-file-name tab-buffer))
           (background (face-background face))
           (icon
            (cond
             ;; Use `all-the-icons-icon-for-file' if current file is exists.
             ((and
               tab-file
               (file-exists-p tab-file))
              (all-the-icons-icon-for-file tab-file :v-adjust awesome-tab-icon-v-adjust :height awesome-tab-icon-height))
             ;; Use `all-the-icons-icon-for-mode' for current tab buffer at last.
             (t
              (with-current-buffer tab-buffer
                (all-the-icons-icon-for-mode major-mode :v-adjust awesome-tab-icon-v-adjust :height awesome-tab-icon-height)
                )))))
      (when (and icon
                 ;; `get-text-property' need icon is string type.
                 (stringp icon))
        ;; Thanks ema2159 for code block ;)
        (propertize
         icon
         'face `(:inherit ,(get-text-property 0 'face icon)
                          :background ,background
                          ))))))
```

the profile tells me that

```
- awesome-tab-icon-for-tab              42522  45%
                           - if                                 42522  45%
                            - and                               42380  45%
                             - condition-case                   42374  45%
                                progn                           42374  45%
```

But the definition of `awesome-tab-icon-for-tab` contain none of `if`, `and`, `condition-case` and `prog`.

What happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at

```el
(when (and awesome-tab-display-icon
             (ignore-errors (require 'all-the-icons)))
```

`when` is a macro defined in `subr.el`:

```el
(defmacro when (cond &rest body)
  "If COND yields non-nil, do BODY, else return nil.
When COND yields non-nil, eval BODY forms sequentially and return
value of last one, or nil if there are none.

\(fn COND BODY...)"
  (declare (indent 1) (debug t))
  (list 'if cond (cons 'progn body)))
```

There you have `if`. The `and` is present in the original code.

`ignore-errors` is also a macro defined in `subr.el`:

```el
(defmacro ignore-errors (&rest body)
  "Execute BODY; if an error occurs, return nil.
Otherwise, return result of last form in BODY.
See also `with-demoted-errors' that does something similar
without silencing all errors."
  (declare (debug t) (indent 0))
  `(condition-case nil (progn ,@body) (error nil)))
```

There you have `condition-case` and `progn`.

The macros are expanded in the compiled code. Therefore, you get their expansions in the profiler output instead of their names.